# Angular JS static site pages

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering what is the best approach for achieving the following requirements. The site has about 5 static pages with a potential for many more in the future. Currently these pages are your typical web pages like home, about, company and so on. The site owner wants the login and signin forms to be modal window that animate in from the top. After authentication the user is redirected to the app which is an angular application.

Normally the signin/login form would be views in angular. I am wondering how to I use angular to deal with the forms while the home page is not actually part of the angular app.

Note the site owner whats the site to be on the same domain. So he doesn't want a static site that redirects to the app once the login/signin button is selected.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question you have asked is too vague to give a really decent answer.  however, it *sounds* like you are going to have to add angular in some capacity to the page, if you intend to use an angular modal on it....

Comment: Yeah I apologize for the way I asked my question. Basically they want a regular website that can show up in Google searches and benefit from SEO, but they want the login/signin to be a modal window on the home page. I do not know if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Well that doesn't really make the question any more answerable; if anything, it makes it less clear.  There isn't any reason at all that a page with angular on it would cause it to not show up on google, and angular can be configured to be SEO friendly, but that is really it's own question.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Google now indexes JavaScript. I just read the article in webmaster tool. Thanks again.